# TYPO3: how to add an element to the RTE, which allows the user to use a defined CSS class

Tags: css, typo3, typoscript, rte

I want that the user should be able to select an textstyle in RTE like Detail, Important, Name of person and so on. So I would like to define a CSS and this option should be shown in RTE. The CSS style should be a `span` and only setting a color.

Currently I have the following code:

```
RTE.classes{
  highlight{
      name = test
      value = color:#0A8AD2;
  } 
}

RTE.default{
  ignoreMainStyleOverride = 1 
  useCSS = 1
  contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte_formats.css
  classesCharacter := addToList(highlight)
  classesParagraph := addToList(highlight)
  proc.allowedClasses := addToList(highlight)
}
```

The content of the CSS file is

```
span.highlight, p.highlight {
    color:#0A8AD2;
}
```

But the new added style isn't shown in the drop down (textstyle). I also enabled "additonal inline elements" in th rtehtmlarea configuration. I also tried to set `showTagFreeClasses` and so on without success. Then I read about caching problems. I deleted the RTE cache as well as the browser cache. Still no result. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are basically on the right track!

I have experienced quite some problems using inlineStyle. One of them being that you have to explicitly undefine the `contentCSS` to make the inlines work (only setting  `ignoreMainStyleOverride = 0` is not enought!):

```
RTE.default.contentCSS >
```

I personally prefer a dedicated external CSS file. The important thing to know is that the TYPO3 RTE really parses this CSS file and only offers those classes that are actually found in there!
So you have to use the `contentCSS` parameter to define a CSS and this CSS must really contain the classes that you want to make available to the user. Here is how you must define it:

```
# TS-Config
RTE.default.ignoreMainStyleOverride = 1
RTE.default.contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte_formats.css
```

The CSS file **must exist** at the give URL and it **must contain** a definition for the CSS class that you want to provide (as said the CSS file is really parsed and missing classes will not show up in the dropdown selector):

```
/* content of rte_formats.css */
/* span. needed for RTE.default.classesCharacter */
/* p.    needed for RTE.default.classesParagraph */
span.highlight, p.highlight{ color:#0A8AD2; }
```

And one more hint:
I recommend not to overwrite the allowedClasses with your own class name(s), but append to them:

```
RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := addToList( highlight, myOtherClass, myThirdClass )
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment and advices. I updated my question with the current TS I have. But I don't know what is wrong ... Do I have to configure RTE in a way that it works or does it works out of the box (after installation)?

Comment: I have thrown your config into a project of mine, completely replacing my TS-Config and my RTE CSS. And it simply works. Here is a [screenshot](http://www.digilog.de/pub/stackoverflow/8741063_add_RTE_classes.png).  
Are you sure you don't have any typos in your config? 
Have you checked the parsed TS-Config using Info module and "Page-TSconfig" selected from the dropdown, to see if all your configuration makes it into the system arrays?

Comment: Oh dear, I never put it in Page TS config ... Now it works! Thanks!